# JavaScript scope and closure: value property does not return incremented value

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, javascript-objects

Confused about how `increment` can change `value` and that changed `value` is accessible to `getValue`, but not to a property of the same object.

Does this have to do with the fact that increment and getValue methods are inner functions of the anonymous function that value is defined in?

```
var myObject = function() {
    var value = 0;

    return {
        increment: function(inc){
            value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
        },
        getValue: function(){
            return value;
        },
        value: value,
    };
}();

console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 0
myObject.increment(2);
console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 2
console.log(myObject.value); // 0
myObject.increment(2); 
console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 4
```

Comment: numbers and strings are copied.

Comment: `value: value` copies the current value of `value`  into the property with the name `value` because it holds a primitive data type, it does not save a reference to it.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with scoping. The reason `myObject.value` returns the original value is because it's never being incremented. The `value` property of the returned object and the inner `value` variable are two different things, they don't relate to each other in any way apart from the circumstance that the property is created with the value that the inner `value` variable initially has.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: It is as @MikaelLennholm says. `myObject.value` is not the same as `myObject.getValue()`. I believe it is confusing to you because of how you named `var value = 0`, try changing it to: `var helloWorld = 0;`. Now when you are doing `myObject.value` because of `value: helloWorld` means that you **should** get 0. Alternatively when you do `myObject.getValue()` you are now working with the scope of the closure within `myObject` and that is what you are modifying via `myObject.increment(inc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var foo` creates a **variable** that is scoped to the function it is declared with in. It can be accessed as `foo` anywhere inside that function or another function declared inside the first function.

`myObject.foo` creates a **property** that is attached to the object. It can be accessed as `???.foo` where `???` is a reference to the object that `myObject` is a reference to. You can do this anywhere you can find a reference to the object.

Properties are not variables. Variables are not properties. (The exception is that global variables are properties of the global (`window` in a browser) object.

---

When you create the object you said:

```
value: value,
```

But that copies the *then current* value of the `value` variable to the `value` property.

That is a number, which isn't a reference.

When you update the `value` variable, the `value` property is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks!  Additionally after reading @PatrickRoberts comment below and doing  bit of research on closure it is clear what is going on.  MyObject.value is just a copy of the value variable declared in the function.  The `increment` and `getValue` methods both have access to `value` because they are declared within the function that defines `value`.  This access to `value` is because of `closure`.

Comment: To add a bit more detail, the methods have access to the context in which they were created.  This means that they have access to the original variable, and not a copy of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers like [@Quentin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464996/1541563) have explained what the issue is pretty thoroughly. Here's a proper way by minimally modifying your current approach to correct the problem though:

```js
var myObject = function() {
  return {
    increment: function(inc) {
      this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    },
    getValue: function() {
      return this.value;
    },
    value: 0
  };
}();

console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 0
myObject.increment(2);
console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 2
console.log(myObject.value); // 2
myObject.increment(2);
console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 4
console.log(myObject.value); // 4
```

However, this functionality would be a great example to make use of an ES6 [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
class Counter {
  constructor (value = 0) {
    this.value = value
  }
  
  increment (amount = 1) {
    this.value += amount
  }
  
  getValue () {
    return this.value
  }
}

let myObject = new Counter()

console.log(myObject.getValue()) // 0

myObject.increment(2)

console.log(myObject.getValue()) // 2
console.log(myObject.value) // 2

myObject.increment(2)

console.log(myObject.getValue()) // 4
console.log(myObject.value) // 4
```

[As was pointed out in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464838/javascript-scope-and-closure-value-property-does-not-return-incremented-value/45465096#comment77891484_45465096), the closure and `getValue()` seem rather pointless. If you want to allow `value` to access a scoped variable, and disable modifying it, you could implement it this way:

```js
var myObject = function() {
  var value = 0;

  return {
    increment: function(inc) {
      value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    },
    getValue: function() {
      return value;
    },
    get value() {
      return value;
    },
    // disable setting it without throwing
    set value(newValue) {
      return value;
    }
  };
}();

console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 0

myObject.increment(2);

console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 2
console.log(myObject.value); // 2

// won't work
myObject.value = 4

// still 2
console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 2
console.log(myObject.value); // 2
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer.  Took too long.

Comment: This also gives complete public access to the `value`, which kind of makes the `getValue()` function pointless

Comment: @MikaelLennholm well, yes, but perhaps there's an underlying reason this simplified example is used. We don't know if the OP has a more complicated program that has been simplified to this, so I don't assume anything.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm you did inspire me to give yet another alternative approach. See my update

Comment: This is a somewhat modified example from the closure chapter in JavaScript: The Good Parts, so this is purely a learning exercise.

With that said... what is `value` that `increment` and `getValue` are pointing to?

Comment: @user2731105 in which example? 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, in my original post.  Confused about how `increment` can change `value` and that changed `value` is accessible to `getValue`, but not to a property of the same object.  I'll edit my response to clarify this question as well.

Comment: @user2731105 in your original post, you have two separate `value`'s, the one in the scope declared `var value = 0`, and the copy you created in the returned object, `value: value`. When `getValue()` and `increment()` were invoked, they both referenced the original scoped `value`, while `myObject.value` referred to the copy made on the returned object literal, which remained `0` since the two functions only accessed and modified the original `value` and not the property on the returned object.